# What does «event coreslct» do in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an AppleScript source with this code:

```
«event coreslct» (last row of table X of document Y)
insert rows selection position below number of rows Z
```

The double angle brackets mean, the enclosed words are [raw format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_raw_data.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH225-SW37) or event code.

So my question is: what is the command of event code `event coreslct`...

Answer (score 1):

The `«event coreslct»` as used in your example is specific to Microsoft Excel, and loosely translates to "select the cells concerned", or simply "select". To determine precisely what the definition of the command is you can perhaps try the instructions below:

*According to Microsoft's KB:*

> To use the program-specific capabilities of Excel for Mac with
>   AppleScript, open and examine the AppleScript dictionary that is
>   supplied with Excel for Mac.
>
> To use the Script Editor open the dictionary in Excel for Mac, follow
>   these steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Start the Script Editor. To do this, follow these steps:
>     a. Open your hard disk.
>     b. Open the Applications folder.
>     c. Open the AppleScript folder. For the Apple OS versions
>        earlier than OSX, open the Apple Extras folder, and then open
>        the AppleScript folder.
>     d. Double-click Script Editor.
> 2. On the File Menu, click Open Dictionary.
> 3. In the Open Dictionary dialog box, select Microsoft Excel 
>    (Application) in the Name list, and then click Open.
> ```
>
> In the window that appears, you can select an object or a class to
>   view its description. You can also click the bold suite names to view
>   an whole suite at one time. You can use the descriptions in this
>   window to create scripts in the Script Editor to control Excel for
>   Mac.
>
> The versions of Excel for Mac listed at the beginning of this article
>   support a very large number of events. For a complete list, follow the
>   instructions in this article to open Excel for Mac in the AppleScript
>   Script Editor.

I don't have access to the Applescript dictionary mentioned above, however, it was ported to Python at some point, and you can view a complete set of commands [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/blob/master/xlwings/mac_dict.py#L5021).

Comment: It looks like `coreslct` is a code from Excel 2011 (it's in the Python dictionary you mentioned), but it's not in my Excel.sdef file...

Comment: @doekman: There's some links referenced at the top of the Python ported dictionary; they're apparently Apple mailing list discussions on the subject, so that might provide some additional info. There doesn't seem to be much information that pops up on google either, so unfortunately this is all I know here.

Comment: The code is not specific to Excel; it appears in all Office applications. Except in Office 2016...

Answer (score 0):

It's the `select` command of Microsoft Word. Wrap around a `tell "Microsoft Word"` block around it and it will be corrected using the application's dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried to enclose the script in a `tell application "Microsoft Word"` block, but it doesn't get replaced... Any idea?

Comment: Restart Word, or even your system. The problem is that the dictionary is not getting loaded into your script editor.

Comment: I now get an error: "Microsoft Word got an error: The object you are trying to access does not exist"

Comment: Does the object exists? Do you have `document Y` open and do you have  an `table X` in that document? The error seems self explanatory and it's trying to access an object that no longer exists. Or is the error happening on line 2?

Comment: The error happens on line 1. The main question is still: where can I this code `coreslct`. Is this the code-attribute in the `sdef` files provided within the package of AppleScript enabled Applications?

Comment: The reason why the line won't get corrected on my computer, is that the `select` command disappeared in Office 2016. I collected some [sdef-files from office](https://github.com/doekman/sdef), and the command is gone in 2016... Not sure if this is a bug, or the command has been replaced.